# Displaying username with $_SESSION['username']

Tags: php, session

i have some question about PHP, i want to display the username of a logged in user. I am now starting with php so i need some help, I found this code on the internet but can someone explain what it means? It will be much appreciated!

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: It says if there is a value that isn't considered empty in superglobal `$_SESSION` under the key `username`, set the variable `$username` to that same value.

Comment: This is far too broad to be explained. There are many tutorials and manuals to consult.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your code checks, if value of key username of superglobal array SESSION isn't empty, and if so, then it saves it's value into variable $username.
If you want to display it's value, you can use

```
echo($_SESSION["username"]);
```

to directly get it from SESSION or, when setting username from session to variable $username (as in your code) you can also use

```
echo($username);
```

---

//EDIT

As other people mentioned, you have to start session at start of each file you want to use it with function `session_start();`

Then you can save data or read data from it, as from any other array.
For more information about arrays (if you don't know, how they work) you can visit [W3Schools - PHP arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

For example:

```
session_start();

//setting value "Ben" into session array to key "username"
$_SESSION["username"] = "Ben";

//displaying value of key "username" from session
echo($_SESSION["username"]);
    //output: Ben
```

For more information about session you can visit [W3Schools - PHP session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: i have a problem which says undefined id.. How can i solve this

Comment: You probably didn't set the username into session. As people in other answers mentioned, you have to start session in each file, you want to use it with function session_start(); Check my edited answer.

Comment: i solved that thanks, i just have one more question. When i have foreach ($users as $entry) do i need to declare the variable entry or should I leave it like this?

Comment: You don't have to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is one of a couple of [superglobals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in PHP meaning that it is accessible regardless of scope.
Every superglobal is an array, thus the code snippet is verifying that the key `'username'` exist and isn't empty and in that case assign its value to the variable `$username`.

Just as a side note, to be able to use PHP's sessions you need to start them with `sessions_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use session_start() start of page ...

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['username'] ?: "Session username not exist";
```

sessions are super global variables and can access from everywhere